# At which point is the argument passed in this closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, memoization

Taken from [Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja](http://jsninja.com), Listing 5.14 passes the **num** argument of *isPrime* to a *memoized function*, I assumed the *num* argument would be visible in **#1**, and not in **#2**, But it's actually The other way around!

```
Function.prototype.memoized = function(key){
  this._values = this._values || {};
  return this._values[key] !== undefined ?
    this._values[key] :
    this._values[key] = this.apply(this, arguments);
};

Function.prototype.memoize = function() {
  var fn = this;                                  //#1
  console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); // Prints []

  return function(){                              //#2
    console.log(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)); //Prints [17]
    return fn.memoized.apply(fn, arguments);
  };
};

var isPrime = (function(num) {
  var prime = num != 1;
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    if (num % i == 0) {
      prime = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return prime;
}).memoize();

assert(isPrime(17), "17 is prime");                //#3
```

How is it possible that the num argument (17 in this case) is visible only in the *inner* closure (#2) and not in the wrapping memoize function? I don't understand at which point the memoize() call **passes** the num argument to the closure in #2.

PS. To reiterate, and complement the Question above: Why can't I see the num argument in #1?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `#2` is the function that is assigned to `isPrime`. And you pass `17` to `isPrime`. On the other hand, you call `.memoize` (`#1`) without passing any arguments to it:

```
(function() { ... }).memoize()
//                          ^^ no arguments
```

> I don't understand at which point the memoize() call passes the num argument to the closure in #2.

It doesn't. `memoize` **returns** a new function and it's that function to which the argument is passed.

Comment: So the memoize call, is really calling the inner anonymous closure, right? it's kind of confusing because the context at #1 is actually the isPrime function, whereas in #2 is window. That's why it didn't make sense to me. Could you explain that a bit please? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: How `this` works is very well explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this). Basically, if you call a function "normall", like `foo()`, then `this` refers to `window` and if you call it as `bar.foo()`, then `this` refers to `bar`. So in your case, when you call `func.memoize()`, `this` refers to `func`. *"So the memoize call, is really calling the inner anonymous closure, right?"* It's not *calling* the inner function. It's *creating* and returning it.

Answer (score 1):

Because at that point, the anonymous function has't been called.

What you are doing is calling `memoize`, with your anonymous function as the `this` value and no arguments (hence the empty `arguments` array)

`memoize` then returns a function, which basically checks "has this function already been called with this argument", and either return the previous value if so, or calls the function and stores its return value if not.

What this means is that your function is only called when you actually do `isPrime(17)`, and at that point your are inside the function where it says `return function() {...}` and that's where you can see your argument.

Comment: I have an additional Question for you, sir... Why is the context (this) inside the anonymous closure the window object? Shouldn't the context be its wrapping function?

Thank you for you kind reply, (it's so difficult to know whom to give the answer acceptance, both answers are great)

Comment: You're calling `isPrime(17)`, there is no context given in this call, therefore the context "defaults" to the window object.